# LT3080 regulator question

Tags: power-supply, voltage, voltage-regulator, load

The [datasheet of the LT3080 voltage regulator](http://cds.linear.com/docs/Datasheet/3080fc.pdf) says that "For true zero voltage output operation, this 1mA load current must be returned to a negative supply voltage."

What exactly does this mean? How can I return the minimum required load current to a negative supply voltage? In case I have a single supply and I generate a negative voltage using a charge pump how would I connect  the minimum load to the negative voltage generated by the charge pump?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Yes, you're going to have to generate a negative voltage somehow.
2. The minimum load could be as simple as a resistor that draws at least 1mA when the output is at zero volts. However, this might be problematic at higher output voltages, because the resistor would dissipate more power and the negative supply would have to deal with the additional current through the resistor. It might make sense to use a transistor to create an active current sink.

If you're using just a resistor, connect it between the output of the LT3080 and the negative supply. Suppose your negative supply is -5V; the value of the resistor would be 5V/1mA = 5000Ω. The standard 5% value of 4700Ω would give you a little extra margin: 5V/4700Ω = 1.06mA.

If you'd like to add an NPN transistor to this, connect the collector to the LTC3080 output, connect the base to ground and connect the resistor between the emitter and the negative supply. The only critical parameter of the transistor is that it needs to be able to handle the maximum voltage that the LT3080 will be producing (Vce(max)). Now, when you calculate the resistor value, you need to allow for the Vbe drop of the transistor. Again, using -5V as the negative supply, the resistor value is now (5V - 0.7V)/1mA = 4300Ω. This happens to be a standard 5% value ... or you could give yourself some margin by using 3900Ω: 4.3V/3900Ω = 1.10mA.

Comment: Yes, all this is true. But this does not answer my question. I already knew all that. What I don't understand is how to do the connections between the minimum required load and the negative supply (charge pump) so that the 1mA load will return to the negative supply. In other words: I don't know how to return the 1mA to a negative supply voltage.

Comment: Sorry, I thought that was obvious. I've added a description of the connections to my answer.